# Using an equation in intercepts, obtain an implicit formula f(x,y)=0 for the straight line

Tags: functions

straight line intersecting the coordinate axes X and Y at the points with  coordinates (2, 0) and (0, -1), respectively.
I'm sorry if this seems elementary but I really need help with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a line has nonzero $x$ and $y$ intercepts $a,\ b$ respectively it has the simple eqution $$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1. \tag{1}$$

Note more fully this works only for a line going through $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$ where each of $a,b$ is nonzero. In particular not for vertical or horizontal lines (which have  simple equations you likely know) or for nonvertical, nonhorizontal lines through the origin (which are $y=kx$ for some $k \neq 0.$)

Comment: May I know how do I use this formula for the given problem?

Comment: In your problem, $a=2,b=-1$ to make line through $(2,0)$ and $(0.-1).$ Plug these into eqn (1)  of my answer. You can then simplify by multiplying all by $2$ or whatever, etc.

Comment: thank you so much! that was such a great help

Comment: The other answers are more general, but I like this version, sometimes called the "intercept-intercept" equation. Advantage-- it's unique (given the x,y intercepts distinct nonzero),

Comment: Oops-- x,y intercepts don't need to be distinct, just nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

The general equation of a line is

$$ax+by+c=0.$$

This equation is fulfilled by any point on the line, as well as the two given points. This corresponds to a $3\times3$ system of equations, which has anon-trivial solution iff

$$\begin{vmatrix}x&y&1\\2&0&1\\0&-1&1\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

This is the seeked equation.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line can be defined as $y=mx+c$ where $m$ is the gradient of the line and $c$ is the $y$-intercept.

We know that the $y$ intercept (where the line crosses the $y$-axis) is $-1$ from the second given coordinate.

From this, we have two options. We could either substitute in the second coordinate and solve for $m$, or we can calculate the gradient directly.

*Option 1*

We can say that \begin{align}y&=mx+c\\
y&=mx-1\\
0&=2m-1\\
2m&=1\\
m&=\frac 12\end{align}

which gives us that $$y=\frac12 x-1$$

*Option 2*

The equation for the gradient of a line is \begin{align}m&=\frac{\text{change in } y}{\text{change in }x}\\
&=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\end{align}

Using our two coordinates, we can say that $(x_1,y_1)=(2,0)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(0,-1)$ and therefore \begin{align}m&=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\\
&=\frac{-1-0}{0-2}\\
&=\frac{-1}{-2}\\
&=\frac 12\end{align}

which gives us the same equation for the line $$y=\frac 12x-1$$